# Is it possible to use CSS Counters To Increment The Rotation Of An Element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-counter

Is it possible to use the CSS Counter function to increment the rotation of an element? For every `<li>` element I would like to rotate it 2 degrees more than the last `<li>` element. I am attemping something like:

```
ul li:nth-of-type( 1n ) {
  counter-increment: rotation;
  transform: rotate( counter(rotation) + 1deg);
}
```

Is this possible to achieve using only CSS?

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't *think* so, because the counters are generated content.

Comment: @Geuis Yeah I can't seem to get it working no matter what I try. I guess I'm going to have to use Javascript.

Comment: I've posted an answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694292/179583, with a link to some relevant CSS-WG discussion from a few years ago: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> [Counter values] can be used with the ‘counter()’ and ‘counters()’ functions. ... [They] can be used by an author anywhere that accepts a <string>.

—[CSS Lists Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-functions)

And `rotate()` doesn't accept a <string>:

> ‘rotate()’ = rotate( [ <angle> | <zero> ] )

—[CSS Transforms Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#two-d-transform-functions)

I thought maybe we could get around that with `calc()`, since it can be used in place of an <angle>, but

> Components of a calc() expression can be literal values or ‘attr()’ or ‘calc()’ expressions.

—[CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)

No <string>s, so that still won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I also tried calc, but I couldn't get it to work. It's kind of a shame as it would be a nice feature, but I guess that's what Javascript is for. Thanks for the input!

Comment: indeed. It is strange that Counters can not be accessed via `calc`, nor `var` while it would make sense to have this consequent implemented. But you can count how often your css fails with counter - lol